# Excel macro to create filter based on existing filter(s)

Tags: excel, vba

I have to work on a spreadsheet that keeps track of multiple purchase orders grouped by contract. The columns include the contract number, the order number, the status of the order, the supplier, etc. Excel's built-in (auto-) filters work for simple cases, but become quite unwieldy when I might want to combine them, e.g. show all purchase orders for contracts where invoices from a particular supplier haven't been received.

I'm trying to write a macro to put in my PERSONAL.XSLB file that adds a "Generate Filter" command that will create a filter based on the currently visible cells in the selected column. I'm already using [this macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52990987/383111) to create an Invert Filter menu entry.

My line of reasoning is that I should be able to add the range of visible values in the currently selected column to an array, clear the existing filter(s), then create a new autofilter from the array variable. I can't figure out how to get Excel to do this.

Comment: This will work correctly only if the values in the mentioned column are unique: you could use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` on the column range, loop through it, writing the values to a column of a worksheet. Then when you need this 'filter', you can write the values to an array and use it as the `Criteria1` parameter with `xlFilterValues` as the `Operator` parameter in the `AutoFilter` method.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks! I was able to figure it out and adapt the macro linked in the original post to do what I wanted. I think it could probably be optimised slightly as it `ReDim`s the array each time a new item is added in order to ensure that the filter array contains only unique items.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quit sure if I understood what you need! Try this and let us know.
Create the tables as shown in picture, apply a filter to table2 and run the code.

[image]

```
Sub Range_FilteredRangeToArray()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim ol1 As ListObject: Set ol1 = ws.ListObjects("table1")
    Dim ol2 As ListObject: Set ol2 = ws.ListObjects("table2")

    ' Clear table filters
    If ol1.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then ol1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        
    ' Get filter data
    Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = ol2.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Dim nRows As Long: nRows = Rng.CountLarge
    
    ' Exit if no filtered rows
    If nRows = ol2.ListRows.Count Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Filtered range to array
    Dim arrTemp() As Variant
    arrTemp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng)
        
    ' Filter using the array as criteria
    Dim olCol As Byte: olCol = ol2.ListColumns("column1").Index
    ol1.Range.AutoFilter field:=olCol, Criteria1:=arrTemp, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```